# Android - function not working when outside main class

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

Im a bit new to Java and Android. Im developing a program to android that one of the needed features is to be able to take a picture with the correct name.

my main class is AmplaCoordenadasActivity

so i made the following code inside it:

```
public void tirarFoto(String arquivo)
{
     Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File(arquivo));
    camera.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(camera, 1);

}
```

and it works fine.

But when i try to put it in another class and call it , it throws many exceptions.
The class:

```
package ampla.giesta.coordenadas;
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;


public class Photo extends Activity{

public void tirarFoto(String arquivo){
    Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File(arquivo));
    camera.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(camera, 1);

}

}
```

And the I write in the main class

```
public void Camera(){
        Photo camera = new Photo();
        camera.tirarFoto("/sdcard/x.jpg");

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you shouldn't `extends Activity` class `Photo`. And How you call `Camera()` method?

Comment: 04-21 01:31:53.152: W/dalvikvm(351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: 04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Comment: 04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

Comment: 04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 01:31:53.182: E/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Camera() is a "onClick" from the XML .......................       <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_Cam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camera" 
            android:onClick="Camera"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the new activity in your android manifest.

Read up on it here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

That's a good intro to the permissions you need to set in the android manifest.  The manifest controls what other app's functions your app can call and respond to, you have to declare services and recievers in your manifest, any special permissions your app needs need to be declared in your manifest, and finally, any additional activities besides your main app activity also need to be declared here.

You also manage intent filters for your activities in the manifest.

try adding

```
<activity android:name=".Photo" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

to your manifest.xml file